# Problem when loading using the OBJLoader in threejs

Tags: three.js

I have 3D object files(a total of 7 items) with `.obj` and `.mtl`extensions. These files are shapes of fences and are exported by the Blender program.

I tried to load these items in a `three.js` project I'm developing and a 3D viewer supported by Windows.

In the 3D viewer program, the models are loaded. However, in my project, the columns of fences have disappeared. Except for columns, the remaining things appear well.

Below are my codes:

```
let objLoader = new OBJLoader();
            mtlLoader.load(`/fence${number of parameter}.mtl`, function (materials) {
                materials.preload();
                objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
                objLoader.load(`/fence${number of parameter}.obj`, function (object) {
                    object.traverse(function(child){
                        if(child instanceof THREE.Mesh){
                            child.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide
                        }
                    })
                    setObj(object)
                });
            });
```

As you see, I'm just adapting examples that are all over the internet. Please help me find the columns of the fences.

Comment: Can you provide the `URL` to the models?